# Easiest way to migrate Availability Group databases from one cluster to another?

Tags: availability-groups, migration, clustering

Consider this scenario:

OLDCLUSTER (WSFC, all nodes SQL Server 2016 SP2)

- OLDSQL01 AG primary node
- OLDSQL02 AG secondary node
- OLDSQL03 AG secondary node (for DR)

NEWCLUSTER (WSFC, all nodes SQL Server 2019)

- NEWSQL01 AG future primary node
- NEWSQL02 AG future secondary node
- NEWSQL03 AG future secondary node(for DR)

So, we have databases DB01 and DB02 hosted on OLDSQL01 (and of course replicated on OLDSQL02 and OLDSQL03, with Availability Group AG01). We want to migrate DB01 and DB02 to NEWSQL01 (and secondary new replicas, creating a new AG).

Do we need a real migration (e.g. Log Shipping) to perform this task? Since NEWSQL01 is already part of NEWCLUSTER, we cannot join it to OLDCLUSTER, wait for DB synchronization and remove it from OLDCLUSTER - right? Is there a best way to do the task (avoiding Distributed AGs)?

I have been looking for information on how to migrate an AG from one cluster to another, the best post I found is this:
[Migrating from old AlwaysOn Availability Group to new AG cluster but keep ip addresses](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/306276/migrating-from-old-alwayson-availability-group-to-new-ag-cluster-but-keep-ip-add)
but it seems a slightly different case (no new cluster, only nodes to add to an existing one).

Comment: Please take a look at the Distributed Availability Groups https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/migration-guides/virtual-machines/sql-server-distributed-availability-group-migrate-ag?view=azuresql